# Hide field programmatically in "manage display"

Tags: entities, 10

I develop a contrib module. I added a new field to "user" entity. I need to hide this field from display in "manage display"

I run this code

```
$entity_view_display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('entity_view_display')
  ->load('user.user.default');
if ($entity_view_display) {
  $entity_view_display->setComponent('field_myfield', [
    'region' => 'hidden',
  ])->save();
}
```

In "manage display" page (/admin/config/people/accounts/display) I see that my field moved to "hidden" region, but when I view user profile I see my field.

If I press "save" button in "manage display" page my field is gone when I view user profile.

How to resave "manage display" programmatically? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EntityDisplayBase::removeComponent()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityDisplayBase.php/function/EntityDisplayBase%3A%3AremoveComponent/):

```
$entity_view_display->removeComponent('field_myfield')->save();
```

Comment: It works, thanks!